# Jmeter JunitSampler NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jmeter

I'm trying to integrate a Selenium JUnit Test to Jmeter using JunitSampler. The unit test runs fine on Eclipse but will fail and produce this error when I use JMeter:

```
2018-07-27 11:24:01,828 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.initializeTestObject(JUnitSampler.java:663) ~[ApacheJMeter_junit.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.threadStarted(JUnitSampler.java:644) ~[ApacheJMeter_junit.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:676) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) [jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) [jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:644) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:632) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:246) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

I did a bit of research and it says it could be Selenium and Jmeter java library conflict. I have imported all the libraries in my Eclipse BuildPath into /lib file, could anyone tell me which library is causing the conflict?
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUtdz.png)[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKLsL.png)[Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsXZu.png)

Comment: What research did you do? Where is the error message you are referring to regarding conflicts? Please add more details.

Comment: did you follow JUnit sampler tutorial: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.html Specificall: Write your JUnit test and jar the classes; Copy and paste the jar files into jmeter/lib/junit directory